# Using previous entry to calculate MS Access vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need to make sure my users are not entering more downtime than they have available. To do this, I calculated the time they have available and made a running total column in the form to show their current minutes of downtime (They enter one downtime reason and "minutes down" at a time).

Now I am trying to write a VBA code that checks the available time against the running total of downtime. It works except for the first entry. If the user enters a number higher than the available time on their first entry, it allows it. I thought it was because I was using "after update" but I tried other events and it didn't change the outcome.

Here is my current VBA Code:

```
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
    If Me.RunTime.Value < Me.DTSum Then
        MsgBox ("You have too much downtime")
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToPrevious 
    Else
        MsgBox ("Okay")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using the [BeforeUpdate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/form-beforeupdate-event-access) trigger event (usually the event for data validation) where you warn the user after entry and before save and then cancel the event accordingly. And for new events use [BeforeInsert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/form-beforeinsert-event-access) trigger event.

With this approach, you avoid delete actions and take on the proactive stance instead of reactive one.

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If Me.RunTime.Value < Me.DTSum Then
        MsgBox ("You have too much downtime")
        Cancel = True
        Me!RunTime.Undo
    Else
        MsgBox ("Okay")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)
    If Me.RunTime.Value < Me.DTSum Then
        MsgBox ("You have too much downtime")
        Cancel = True
        Me!RunTime.Undo
    Else
        MsgBox ("Okay")
    End If
End Sub
```

Or use a function for a DRY-er solution:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Cancel = CheckRunTime
    Me!RunTime.Undo
End Sub

Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)
    Cancel = CheckRunTime
    Me!RunTime.Undo
End Sub

Function CheckRunTime As Integer
    Dim Cancel As Integer

    If Me.RunTime.Value < Me.DTSum Then
        MsgBox ("You have too much downtime")
        Cancel = True
    Else
        MsgBox ("Okay")
        Cancel = False
    End If

    CheckRunTime = Cancel
End Sub
```